# Sort list for date in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, sorting, lambda

```
import re

arr1 = ['2018.07.17 11:30:00,-0.19', '2018.07.17 17:55:00,0.86']
arr2 = ['2018.07.17 11:34:00,-0.39', '2018.07.17 17:59:01,0.85']

def combine_strats_lambda(*strats):
    """
    Takes *strats in date,return format
    combines infinite amount of strats with date, return and packs them into 
    one
    single sorted array

   >> RETURN: combined list

   """
   temp = []

   # create combined list
   for v in enumerate(strats):
       i = 0
       while i < len(v[1]):
           temp.append(v[1][i])
           #k = re.findall(r"[\w']+", temp)[:6]
           i += 1

    temp2 = sorted(timestamps, key=lambda d: tuple(map(int, re.findall(r"[\w']+", d[0]))))

    return temp2
```

Hi,

I've been trying to finish this function, which should combine multiple lists of dates,percentage returns and sort them.

I've come across a solution with lambda but all I get is this message:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Do you know an easier solution to the problem or what the error is caused by? I can't seem to figure it out.

Anything appreciated :)

Comment: Like the error says, it expected something string-y; `temp` is a *list*.

Comment: @ RafaelC: return sorted((arr1+arr2), key=lambda k: k.split(',')[0]) that's all I need in the function, very elegant. Thank you

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, Glad you could see in time haha :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very basic error in your code is in line:

```
for v in enumerate(strats):
```

You have apparently forgotten that `enumerate(...)` returns **two**
values: the **index** and the current **value** from the iterable.

So, as you used just **single** `v`, it gets the **index**, not the **value**.

Another important point is that if the datetime strings are written as
`yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss`, you can sort them using just string sort.

So, to gather the strings, you need a *list comprehension*, with 2 nested
loops.

And to sort them, you should use `sorted` function, specifying as the sort
key the "initial" (date / time) part, before the comma.

To sum up, to get the sorted list of strings, taken from a couple of
arguments of your function, sorted on the date / time part,
you can use the following program, written using version 3.6 of Python:

```
arr1 = ['2018.07.17 11:30:00,-0.19', '2018.07.17 17:55:00,0.86']
arr2 = ['2018.07.17 11:34:00,-0.39', '2018.07.17 17:59:01,0.85']

def combine_strats_lambda(*strats):
    temp = [ v2 for v1 in strats for v2 in v1 ]
    return sorted(temp, key = lambda v: v.split(',')[0])

res = combine_strats_lambda(arr1, arr2)
for x in res:
    parts = x.split(',')
    print("{:20s} {:>6s}".format(parts[0], parts[1]))
```

It does not even use `re` module.